# Extent of data seperation within multiple user accounts in Android

Tags: account-security

What is the extent to which data is separated between user accounts on Android? For example, can I have a different facebook account/any other social media account on each and trust these won't be linked in any way?

Comment: I don't have any references, but you should assume it is isolated at a convenience level, but not actually protecting the device or other users from a malicious user.